# Clean method and validation of individual fields

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model with some fields with **blank=False**.

I have a form:

```
class FipiForm(ModelForm):

    def _validate_ready_for_whole_exam(self, cleaned_data):
           ...

    def _validate_modify_spoilt_task(self, cleaned_data):
           ...

    def _validate_correspondene_of_modification_to_task(self, cleaned_data):
           ...


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean() # Breakpoint
        self._validate_ready_for_whole_exam(cleaned_data)
        self._validate_modify_spoilt_task(cleaned_data)
        self._validate_and_modify_spoilt_task(cleaned_data)
        self._validate_and_modify_spoilt_task(cleaned_data)
        self._validate_correspondene_of_modification_to_task(cleaned_data)

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = FipiTask
        exclude = []
```

[image]

I intentionally left some fields empty.

Well, form is not valid.

What I'd like to have is delegate validation of fields to Django. And in clean method I would like to validate interdependence between fields.

In other words I thought that if method super().clean() has been called, blank=False has already been validated. But I was wrong.

Could you tell me what to do: either validate individual fields here, in "clean" method? But that looks contrary to the idea of the framework.